# communicate with iphone via USB port on mac

Tags: iphone, usb

So what I need help with is communicating with the iphone via a mac program.  I don't want to do complicated stuff, I mainly just want to send the "screenshot" command, much like xcode does in the organizer window, however I want to be able to do my own things with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check http://code.google.com/p/iphonedisk/

It uses MacFUSE.  While it seems to have some problems it is a good start and I was using it a couple of years ago.

Comment: ok, now were are starting to get somewhere, now all I need is the command to send to have the iphone take a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This site lists a way to connect to SSH through a USB connection:

http://oss.coresecurity.com/iphonedbg/usb_tunnel_doc.htm

It would be useful for a jailbroken iPhone.

As for other possibilities I haven't looked into, [iphuc](http://code.google.com/p/iphuc/) might be able to do get you just the screenshot capability without requiring you to be jailbroken.  You will probably need to sniff them while running the organizer.

Comment: eh. iphuc doesn't quite work the way I want it, plus it seems that the latest version was 2 years ago..  and the USB tunnel I haven't looked too far into yet

Comment: yea the usb one won't work as well, it seems to be windows only

Comment: I did some searches and found a Windows and Mac program called iPhone Tunnel.  Some source is available and a Mac compiled version although I'm not sure the Mac version is iPhone OS 3.x compatible.

http://web.me.com/novi.mad/page3/page3.html

http://www.webisee.com/2009/06/22/download-working-iphone-tunnel-suite-27-for-os-30/

Comment: only for windows?  The mac version doesn't run